Issue with Annotation Box Position in Grafana 10.4.3 on MacBook (Chrome Browser)
Upon clicking an annotation, the box related to the annotation is removed from the visible area of the page. This makes it impossible to view the details of the annotation.
I am trying to make the annotation box more accessible by adjusting its position so that it opens at the top of the page instead of being removed from the view when clicked.
I expected the annotation box to appear in a fixed or more accessible position, preferably at the top of the page, so that it remains visible and accessible regardless of where the annotation is located on the graph.
I am using Grafana version 10.4.3 on a MacBook with macOS. My browser is Chrome.

